# Unable to use exported YOLOv7 to TensorFlow Lite, in ObjectDetector

Tags: android, pytorch, object-detection, tensorflow-lite, yolov7

I have a [YOLOv7](https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7) model trained on my custom dataset. I exported the model to TensorFlow lite successfully and was able to use it for inference in Python. But when I try to use the same model in Android, using the [object detection project with TensorFlow lite](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android), it throws this error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error occurred when initializing ObjectDetector: The input tensor should have dimensions 1 x height x width x 3. Got 1 x 3 x 640 x 640.`

Is it possible to change the input shape for the **ObjectDetector** class, or export the YOLOv7 or [YOLOv5](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/) model with corresponding input shape?

I tried to tweak the export process to change the input shape of ONNX model which is the intermediate model in exporting from PyTorch to TensorFlow Lite but it throws this error:

`ONNX export failure: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 3, 3, 3], expected input[1, 640, 640, 3] to have 3 channels, but got 640 channels instead`

update: I used onnx2tf to export .tflite model with NHWC input shape. Now the Android project throws this error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred when initializing ObjectDetector: Input tensor has type kTfLiteFloat32: it requires specifying NormalizationOptions metadata to preprocess input images.`
I couldn't find a way to add normalization options to metadata using this [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/convert/metadata). Any solutions?

Comment: learn about "NHWC" and "NCHW"

Comment: That's right. The problem is that my exported model is NCHW and ObjectDetector expects NHWC models. However, I couldn't save the model along with a transpose layer.

Comment: Are you able you able to use [PyTorch Mobile](https://pytorch.org/mobile/android/) for Android rather than Tensorflow Lite?

Comment: You could also convert onnx to tf, then change nchw to nhwc using [this process](https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-convert-between-nhwc-and-nchw-in-tensorflow/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The ONNX export error:
   Rearrange the dimensions to NHWC format. Then, when exporting from ONNX to TensorFlow, ensure that the NHWC format is retained.

   nhwc_tensor = input_tensor.permute(0, 2, 3, 1)
2. TensorFlow Lite Input Preprocessing:
   The error Input tensor has type kTfLiteFloat32: it requires specifying NormalizationOptions metadata to preprocess input images. (You need to specify how the input image should be normalized before passing it through the model).

Add normalization metadata to your .tflite model:

```
import tflite_support
from tflite_support.metadata_writers import image_classifier
from tflite_support.metadata_writers import writer_utils
from tflite_support import metadata

NORMALIZATION_MEAN = [127.5]
NORMALIZATION_STD = [127.5]

writer = image_classifier.MetadataWriter.create_for_inference(
    writer_utils.load_file("your_model.tflite"),
    input_norm_mean=NORMALIZATION_MEAN,
    input_norm_std=NORMALIZATION_STD)

writer_utils.save_file(writer.populate(), "your_model_tflite_here")
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough reply. I could successfully write the metadata to the model. But now this error occurs: `Mobile SSD models are expected to have exactly 4 outputs, found 1.`
Is there any way that I can make the model compatible to this code?

Comment: TensorFlow expects a model structure like Mobile SSD architecture.
YOLO usually has one consolidated output tensor, containing all information.

Probably easiest to adjust the Android inference code to handle the single output tensor from your YOLO model.

First find where the model's output tensors are being processed in the Android project. Then modify the code to interpret the YOLO output format. (Extracting bounding box data, class scores, applying non-maximum suppression).

Hope it helps. Sorry I'm not very fast with my replies, excessively busy.